# Magento2 admin edit form prepare form registry error

Tags: magento2, admin, forms, adminform

I have created Magento2 admin edit form but on my edit form I got the error as below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Main.php:110

code is **$formObject->getId()** Is there something missing?

In my Main.php which is reside on **"app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Main.php"**

my function is as below:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $formObject = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('thoscene_product');
    $isElementDisabled = false;

    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('product_');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Product Information')]);

    if ($formObject->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'name',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __('Name'),
            'title' => __('Name'),
            'required' => true,
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'sku',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'sku',
            'label' => __('Sku'),
            'title' => __('Sku'),
            'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
        ]
    );

    $form->setValues($formObject->getData());
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!...

Comment: check if you have set 'thoscene_product' registry properly and you are getting data from that

Comment: Did you set data in registry from Edit.php controller of your module?

Comment: I followed this link https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html

Comment: in registery it does not getting data. @Piyush

Comment: In controller Edit.php, Please print_r($model->getData()); before this->_coreRegistry->register('simplenews_news', $model); line and check did you get record or not.

Comment: it is showing data @rohan

Comment: You have to change your registry name, you are saving registry with different name and trying to get data by other name

Comment: I got the issue. there are two mistakes one with register name and second one is for tab names.

Thanks all for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Changes `if ($formObject->getId()) {` to `if ($formObject && $formObject->getId()){`

$formObject is a registry variable, so,  it **return** `false` when a registry variable does not exit.

Comment: I used your suggested code now my form does not showing any field. it is showing only buttons. like. save, back, delete, etc.

Comment: From your shared code. it is too tough to understand what is an issue with your code. Need to check whole module. I suggest, Follow a good article to implement.Like https://www.folio3.com/blog/the-development-steps-for-conventional-admin-form-grid-store-filter-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

Developers like us always make mistake to identify `registry_name` used to save the data.

- Always note that registry is set in `Controller/Adminhtml/YourController/Edit.php` file.
- `$this->_coreRegistry->register('this_is_registry_name', $model);` 
  Find this line and use this registry name to resolve the issue.